# how to count "clicks" in a remote JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a JS file that I hand to my friend that presenting some DIV in his website.

I now building the next version of this file and I will hand it to him also, but on this version I want to count the amount of "clicks" his users clicked on this DIV.

(on click, its suppose to go to some  tag, to some other website..

I thought I might redirect him to my .aspx page, count it, and the redirect it to the requested page, but I wonder if thats the best way to implement it ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to maintain a click count on a server, then you will either have to do something like your redirect idea or you'll have to make some sort of request to your server and wait for that request to be processed before processing the click and going to a new page.  A request to your server can be either something like an ajax call to a script on your server or it can even be something as simple as an img request (with random param in the URL to prevent caching) that your server counts.  To assure that the ajax call or img load is processed, you will have to wait for it to be successful before going to the new page.

If you just want to maintain the count on the client, then you can use a cookie or local storage to keep the click count.  That count can be updated immediately and then have the click go to the new page.

Comment: if you go with the ajax request, and the click is on a hyperlink, then you will have to handle the click event on the hyperlink and make a synchronous 'ajax' request in that event handler. this will delay the click on the link from reaching the default behavior of navigation until the request ends. the drawback is that untill server responds, it will freeze the page, resulting in poor user experience. see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ async: false

Comment: @CodeToad - yes, ALL methods that want to reliably send a request to a server from your page BEFORE going to a new page must wait some period of time for the request to be processed to guarantee that it works.  The redirect idea also has to wait for another server request to be processed too.  The browser simply isn't very good at solving this particular problem.  If one was actually implementing this, then you would probably need to show some sort of visual indicator that the new page was starting to load so the user knows something is happening.  But, it would delay the loading of new page.

Comment: @jfriend00 - What if Im opening it on a new tab?  will it fix that problem?

Comment: you can't be sure of new tab because browser settings can dictate the behavior of target="_blank"

Comment: @thormayer - if the new tab/window opens successfully (isn't blocked in any way), then the opening of the new window is a synchronous operation so you will not have to wait to process the click and allow the current page to go to its new link.